# The type or namespace name could not be found (are you missing a using directive or an assembly reference

Tags: wpf, xaml

I have Downloaded one project from internet when tried to include to my main project It is showing Clr namespace Error Please help me I have already added dll file in reference what should i do ?? Its showing error in SiriusMicrotech clr namespace..

```
//My Coding//



<Page x:Class="RTBSPROJECT.Point_Of_Sale.Invoice"
      xmlns="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml/presentation"
      xmlns:x="http://schemas.microsoft.com/winfx/2006/xaml"
      xmlns:mc="http://schemas.openxmlformats.org/markup-compatibility/2006" 
      xmlns:d="http://schemas.microsoft.com/expression/blend/2008"

       xmlns:ig="http://schemas.infragistics.com/xaml" 
       xmlns:SiriusMicrotech="clr-namespace:SiriusMicrotech.core.UI"

      mc:Ignorable="d" 

    Title="Invoice"  >
    enter code here

   <Page.Resources>


 <ResourceDictionary>
            <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
                <ResourceDictionary Source="Point Of Sale\TouchStyle.xaml"/>
            </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
        </ResourceDictionary>
</page.Resources>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Hi you also need to specify the Assembly along with namespace when you use assembly other than current assembly

```
xmlns:SiriusMicrotech="clrnamespace:SiriusMicrotech.core.UI;assembly=AssemblyName....."
```

I hope this will help.

Comment: AssemblyName means the name of Assmebly of which the namespace clrnamespace:SiriusMicrotech.core.UI is